# HTML5 swipe colored objects in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried something with canvas but I don't find a solution to my problem.
I have a canvas 250x250px, and in this canvas, I tried to make some colored objects (50x50px, 24 objects with different colors, one field is empty).
Now I want to swipe one object to put it in a row or column and the other objects should swipe in that direction in this canvas.

[image]
Is this possible with multi-touch events on canvas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question gets even bigger when there is no info about what lib or approach you made in general.

Comment: i have tryed it with pixi but it seems there is no collision part.

Comment: now i use matter.js and this works fine. Is there a solution to get multitouch on matter.js?